# Angular ui-router customization issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am in trouble with a specific requirement here for our Application.

We a are setting-up an angular application inside a pre-existent Rails Application.

As a full refactor of our code-base is currently out-of-the-question we are dealing with some hard customization and hackings on both sides to allow a incremental introduction of Angular.

What we need for now is a way to tell the ui-router to bind only to the links we have the ng-sref attribute and do not bother with all the regular href links within our app.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior ?

Below is my current code:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('test', {
                    url: "/1/test",
                    template: 'test'
                });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false,
                rewriteLinks: false
            })
        }
    )
```

With this approach, all links, even those ones without any route setup for it, and without a ui-sref attribute, are being watched by angular routing service and prevented to work like it`s previous behaviour. I do not want to add every route of our huge app to the angular routing setup (this is a terrible idea) because most of theses links are to non-angular pages. I just want angular routing service to ignore this links, or these locations that are not defined. Maybe a setting for the $location service to let those guys fallow along with its previous behaviour (ajax requests, regular requests, or Turbolinks requests). I am pretty sure this is something really trivial that I might be missing the point.

What happens when I click on theses links is that the window location changes, but nothing happen. The browser request is not triggered.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: if the ui-router has a url that matches the href, it will go there. if you do not have matching urls(or none) then it will only match what is set up there

Comment: Thanks! But this is not working for me. Maybe because I am using the html5mode. I have added my current code inside que question.

Answer (score 0):

```
###################################################################################
# My suggestion is use the ui-router to route to specific pages as shown
# in the example below.

# <a ui-sref="/login">
# <a ui-sref="/logout">
# <a ui-sref="/signup">
# <a ui-sref="/profile">

# 'ui-sref' will take you to the specific pages.

# You can also use '$state.go' to take you to specific pages as shown below.

# $state.go('authentication.login');
# $state.go('authentication.logout');
# $state.go('authentication.signup');
# $state.go('authentication.profile');

###################################################################################

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.foo.authentication')
        .config(moduleConfig);

    /* @ngInject */
    function moduleConfig($translatePartialLoaderProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/foo/authentication');

        $stateProvider
        .state('authentication.login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'app/foo/authentication/login/login.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('authentication.logout', {
            url: '/logout',
            templateUrl: 'app/foo/authentication/logout/logout.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'LogoutController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('authentication.signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: 'app/foo/authentication/signup/signup.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'SignupController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('authentication.profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'app/foo/authentication/profile/profile.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: I believe my problem might be with the html5 option enabled. This simple basic approach does not work for me. I have added my current code above.

Comment: Thanks. But this does not work for me. I have added some more explanation to my question.